# I have two view controllers on the story board, I can connect one VC to code in one swift file, but can't connect the second.

Tags: ios, swift

So, as my title describes, I can connect one view controller in my story board to the first view controller.swift file but unable to connect the second view controller in story board to my second view controller.swift file.  Any reason for this?  Am I missing something?

Thanks for any help,
Jon

Comment: How do you "connect" a Storyboard in your code? You can create a new class for the second `UIViewController`. class SecondViewController: UIViewController { // put stuff here }. Make sure you name the second ViewController by clicking on its yellow button and naming it SecondViewController or whatever.

Comment: check second view controller.swift is subclassed with UIViewController Enter you second view controller.swift few lines of  code from top. I can see how it is written.

Comment: I created a new class for the second view controller.  But when I "control drag" the second view controller to this new class, there is no connection being made.  As in, when I drag the visual view controller over, no horizontal blue line appears and I am given no options.

Comment: Ill check the subclass.

Comment: I have the proper subclass.

Comment: Click on ViewController and see the custom class give the name of your viewcontroller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a ViewController-class to your ViewController in your Storyboard by following the steps below:

[image]

But you have to make sure that you have created your class correctly.

To do that do the following:

1. `File->New->File->iOS-Source->Cocoa Touch`
2. At Subclass of you have to choose: `UIViewController`
3. Add a name, click <kbd>Next</kbd> and <kbd>Create</kbd>
4. Now you can add your created controller like mentioned above.

Comment: I am choosing the class to be UI View Controller, but the text becomes greyed out and a little arrow in a circle appears to the right of the text.

Comment: I've added a little tutorial to my answer. Follow that tutorial and you should be able to connect them.

Comment: I did exactly as you said, still having problems :/

Comment: Is your controller really a UIViewController?

Comment: Maybe you're on to something.  In story board, I have a view controller.  In code, I have a class "second controller" which is a subclass of UI View controller.  so far so good?

Comment: You can join my chatroom so we can talk. Otherwise this discussion will be to long for the comments: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70058/here-to-help

Comment: I would... if i had level 20 status haha.

Comment: IF you want I could check your code. Teamviewer is an app which allows other persons to see and control your screen.
If you don't want that, no problem. But I think it would be helpful. You can download the tool here: http://teamviewer.com

Comment: how do you want to do this?

Comment: There's the problem with teamviewer. You have an ID and a (one time) password. You'd have to give me your Id first and after that your one time password.

Comment: I can't connect. have you started teamviewer?

Comment: the last four digits were the password

Comment: Everything done. :) Please accept my answer by clicking on the 'tick'. That way, everybody with the same problem finds the answer easier. :)